# Can't build Kitura Server using Postgres Adapter with Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, postgresql, kitura

I'm currently trying to build an example Kitura server accessing a Postgres Database.  There are several example projects in github, originally published by IBM.  But with a big comment across the top stating they no longer support this project.

The current project I'm working with is  [TodoList-SWiftKuery](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/TodoList-SwiftKuery).

As stated in the the instructions I clone the project and enter the build command

`swift build`

The link step fails ... here is the console log of when things start to fail. I clip it when it starts to get redundant.

```
Linking ./.build/debug/Server
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/usr/local/lib/libswiftDispatch.dylib', /usr/local/lib/libswiftDispatch.dylib compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/usr/local/lib/libswiftIOKit.dylib', /usr/local/lib/libswiftIOKit.dylib compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/usr/local/lib/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib', /usr/local/lib/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/usr/local/lib/libswiftDarwin.dylib', /usr/local/lib/libswiftDarwin.dylib compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/usr/local/lib/libswiftFoundation.dylib', /usr/local/lib/libswiftFoundation.dylib compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/usr/local/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib', /usr/local/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0)
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/usr/local/lib/libswiftCore.dylib', /usr/local/lib/libswiftCore.dylib compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SwiftObject", referenced from:
      __TMC6Server6Config in Config.swift.o
      __TMC9LoggerAPI3Log in Logger.swift.o
      __TMC6Socket6Socket in Socket.swift.o
      __TMC10SSLService10SSLService in SSLService.swift.o
      __TMC9KituraNet10BufferList in BufferList.swift.o
      __TMC9KituraNet13ClientRequest in ClientRequest.swift.o
      __TMC9KituraNetP33_49D1A1CDD172EED7D059EF5A54A69CBD11CurlInvoker in ClientRequest.swift.o
```

My basic question is how do I fix this!

But a specific lead-in question is, where are the old Swift 2.0 libraries `libswiftDispatch.dylib` et.al.  specified?  Where can I correct this.   It is not in the package manager file.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "TodoList",
    targets: [
        Target(
            name: "Server",
            dependencies: [.Target(name: "TodoList")]
        ),
        Target(
            name: "TodoList"
        )
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura.git",                 majorVersion: 1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/HeliumLogger.git",           majorVersion: 1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-cfenv.git",            majorVersion: 1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-Kuery-PostgreSQL.git", majorVersion: 0)
    ]
)
```

Help or pointers to additional documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had an old version of "kylef/swiftenv: Swift Version Manager"  ... I did a `brew remove swiftgen`, cleared up the problem.

I found it with this command ... when I was researching where the old libraries came from.

`ls -l /usr/local/lib/libswift*`

Lots of results like this

`libswiftObjectiveC.dylib -> ../Cellar/swiftgen/2.0.0/lib/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib`